# $f$ is analytic in the unit disk such that $|f(1/n)|\leq e^{-\sqrt{n}}$. Prove that $f$ Is identically zero.

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

$f(z)$ is analytic in the unit disk such that $|f(1/n)|\leq e^{-\sqrt{n}}$ for $n=2,3,...$ Prove that $f$ Is identically equal to zero.

My Attempt:

Consider the Taylor expansion $$f(z)=f(0)+f'(0)+\frac{f''(0)}{2!}+\frac{f'''(0)}{3!}+...$$By Cauchy estimate, for some $r=\frac{1}{n}$, we have $$\frac{|f^{(k)}|}{k!}\leq\frac{e^{-\sqrt{n}}}{(1/n)^k}$$

As $n\rightarrow \infty$, for each $k$, we have $\frac{|f^{(k)}|}{k!}=0$. Then, Taylor expansion suggests that $f(z)$ is identically zero.

I feel like I'm missing a lot of pieces. Any help or input is appreciated.

Comment: You're not applying Cauchy's estimate correctly. The RHS of Cauchy's estimate involves a $\sup_{|z| = r} |f(z)|$ term, not just $|f(r)|$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what you mean when you write “for some $r=\frac1n$”.

It follows from the squeeze theorem that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f\left(\frac1n\right)=0$. So, unless $f$ is the null function, the Taylor series of $f$ about $0$ will be of the type$$f(z)=a_kz^k+a_{k+1}z^{k+1}+\cdots$$with $k\in\mathbb N$ and $a_k\neq0$. So $\left(\left\lvert f\left(\frac1n\right)\right\rvert\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ behaves as $\frac{\lvert a_k\rvert}{n^k}$. But $\left(e^{-\sqrt n}\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ goes to $0$ much faster than that:$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{\lvert a_k\rvert}{n^k}}{e^{-\sqrt n}}=\lvert a_k\rvert\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{e^{\sqrt n}}{n^k}=\infty.$$

Comment: I'm just curious about the last line. What's the purpose of that in the proof? How does showing the ratio diverges show that $f$ is identically zero?

Comment: I assumed that $f$ is *not* the null function. Then I reached a contradiction (that final limit shouldn't be $\infty$). Therefore, $f$ *is* the null function.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Nobody is saying $f$ behaves as $e^{-\sqrt{n}}$, just that $f$ decays quicker than it. The inequalities implicit in your proof work in your favor though, so all is fine.

Comment: @mathworker21 You are right. I've edited my answer. I hope that everything is correct now.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I think you mean "with $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $a_k \not = 0$"

Comment: @mathworker21 I've edited my answer (again). Thank you.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thanks. Also, I don't see the need to first note $f(\frac{1}{n}) \to 0$. Always, as long as $f$ is not the null function, you have $f(z) = a_kz^k+a_{k+1}z^{k+1}+\dots$ with $a_k \not = 0$ and $k \ge 0$ (instead of $k \in \mathbb{N}$). But having $k = 0$ is not an issue for your proof.

Comment: @mathworker21 You are right again, but I don't think that that's important enough to edit my answer once again.